# Are layers the only way to composite graphics on JavaFX canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, graphics

I am working on a gui in JavaFX which needs to **composite a large number of objects** (often using alpha masks and similar) on the canvas.

For comparison on the HTML5 canvas this can easily be done by the `drawImage` function with the help of a temporary canvas object outside the DOM structure. For example to draw an image on the canvas with an alpha mask, I first draw the image on the temporary canvas, draw (i.e. blit) the mask over it using `globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in"`, then draw the temporary canvas on the original one using composite mode `source-over`. The temporary canvas can be re-used for each such operation. Easy as pie.

However, from what I can see so far the recommended way of doing this in JavaFX is the use of **grouped layers**, i.e. multiple overlayed canvas nodes which never get "flattened".

I could have done it like this in HTML5 too but in my most recent project this would have resulted in **dozens or hundreds of visible layers** which is obviously extremely silly. My approach gave me excellent performance.

That being said, is there a reasonable way to do the same thing on the JavaFX canvas? I consider manually performing pixel-by-pixel copying to be a clunky last-resort thing.

What am I missing? Am I thinking about JavaFX in a wrong way?

Comment: Can't you use `GraphicsContext` to draw your paths/images etc. and set the global blending mode to what suits each operation?

Comment: @Itai Unfortunately it looks like I can't; masked drawing requires two consecutive operations (the mask and the masked image). Performing them in the main canvas would mess up previous content/background which is supposed to remain. Consider it like a bitwise logical operation: `A & (B & C)` where B and C are mask and sprite to apply the mask to. The bracket represents the temporary/overlaying canvas. It cannot be dispensed with totally without distorting the contribution of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before on JavaFx and Android I didn't know they do so on HTML 5 
so anyway 
you can do the same as you do on HTML 5 you can create what is called `mainCanvas` that canvas contains the finished version of another one let's say `tempCanvas` in the temp canvas you draw what ever you want and apply the masks you want too then you take a snapshot of the canvas ( as `Canvas` is a `Node` you can use this code to take a snap shot of it)

```
WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(mainCanvas.getWidth(), mainCanvas.getHeight());
tempCanvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);

GraphicsContext context = mainCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
context.drawImage(writableImage,mainCanvas.getWidth(), mainCanvas.getHeight());
```

Comment: The problem is that taking snapshots is slow. Apparently JavaFX collects drawing calls into an inaccessible buffer and only renders them at the end of each graphics pulse, so the snapshot has to wait for that and can only use the result in the *next* pulse. It is a limitation of the architecture. I don't think there can be a better solution than this, which is sad. But thank you!